TeX does not recognize the new pageno. (Self constructed table)
In this example, TeX does not realize the change of the page and the pageno. If you uncomment the \break, you will see the difference at the beginning of page 2. The first number of every cell is the pageno.
 \TeX
    \input plipsum
\vskip\baselineskip
        \parindent=0pt
        \hoffset-0in
        \hsize=6.5in%from plain.tex
        \vsize=8.9in%from plain.tex
        \raggedright
        \newcount\columns
        \newcount\column
        \column=0
        \newcount\limit
        \limit=8
        \newcount\cells
        \cells=1
        \newdimen\csize
        \columns=0%starting number of columns
        \def\ault{Error}
%calculation
    \csize=\hsize \divide\csize by\limit
%end of calculation
        \def\cell#1{\vtop{\hsize=\csize #1\vskip\baselineskip}\advance\cells by 1}
        \def\floor{ \advance\column by 1 \hbox{\loop\cell{\the\pageno.\the\column.\the\cells} \advance \columns  by 1\ifnum \columns<\limit\repeat}} %floor is just another name for a line
%question is here
\floor\floor\floor \floor\floor\floor \floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor
%\break %uncomment this
\floor\floor\floor\floor \floor\floor\floor \floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor\floor
%question is here
\bye


the page number is incremented in the output routine asynchronously with the macros expanding in the main document flow. You need something like latex's \pageref to pick up the correct number on a second pass. (It would be simpler to use a real document format not plain tex which is just a basic example  for the texbook)

@David Carlisle  One thing off topic : I tried in another file to make cells in tables directly accessible.  Would it not be a nice feature to extend your longtable likewise? As you can see in this example, every cell has a distinct number, \pageno.\floor.\cell ...  and, with some conditionals, one may say : \cell{x,y,z}{content}.
This might be a way, to store data externally, rather than to write them into the table.

@MBE why not use one of the several packages which already offer that functionality with rather more convenient input syntax? specifying cells by the number of the page they may or may not end up on would hardly be a reliable or maintainable way to input data. even the smallest changes to content or layout earlier in the document would require checking, if not changing, the input.

If you only consider forced page breaks like the \break in your example then of course the problem is trivial as you just make your page break command increment a counter, but for automatic page breaks you need to implement writing to an .uax file and reading it back on a second run, you can not reliably get a page number from within the TeX run. any format designed for document production will have that set up already, eplain, optex, context, latex, .... so you shouldn't be needing to allocate a new file just for this.

@cfr
Ok, using the pageno is not a good idea. Which packages do address tablecells directly?

I'm not sure what you mean. you were suggesting it as a way to specify data outside a table specification. there are several packages which do that. but I am not sure what you meany by addressing cells directly. maybe you want something like tabularray? but this is all very far from plain (as, of course, is longtable).

I'm really not clear what this question is asking at this point ....

@cfr Please have a look at : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/729651/how-to-check-empty-cells-in-a-table-conditional-table . It is an example for adressing cells.
