How to check empty cells in a table? Conditional table
PDFTEX!
!Updated, because \cells and \columns do the same!
!Updated, following David Carlisle's answer.!
In this example, I constructed a table, where cells can be directly accessed. With the \newtable{x}{y} command, a new table is defined, with lines and columns. With the
\condition[1,1,4]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}%

command, the cell is filled. This table does not use &.
Now, if a cell is empty, the change (move to next) of the cell does not work, so, I have to add a character. How may I check, if a cell is empty and add something invisible?
     \vskip\baselineskip
        \parindent=0pt
        \hoffset-0in
        \hsize=6.5in%from plain.tex
        \vsize=8.9in%from plain.tex
        \raggedright
        \newcount\columns
        \columns=1
        \newcount\floors
        \floors=0%floor is just another name for a line
        \newcount\limit
        \newcount\cells
        \cells=0
        \newcount\tables
        \tables=0
        \newdimen\csize
        \def\ault{Error}
                %start conditional
        \limit=1%limit must be defined before condition
\def\condition[#1,#2,#3]#4{\ifnum\columns>\limit \else \ifnum\the\tables=#1 \ifnum\the\floors=#2 \ifnum\the\columns=#3 #4\fi\fi\fi\fi}

%beg conditionals
 \def\conditionals{
\condition[1,1,1]{Numbers replaced with text}%
\condition[1,1,2]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}%
\condition[1,1,3]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}%
\condition[1,1,4]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}%
\condition[1,1,5]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}% 
\condition[1,1,6]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}%
\condition[1,1,7]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}%
\condition[1,5,1]{-}%
\condition[1,5,2]{-}%
\condition[1,5,3]{-}%
\condition[1,5,4]{-}%
\condition[1,5,5]{Numbers replaced with text}%
\condition[1,5,6]{.}%
%
\condition[1,2,1]{Numbers replaced with text}%
\condition[1,2,2]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}%
\condition[1,2,3]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}%
\condition[1,2,4]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}%
\condition[1,2,5]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}% 
\condition[1,2,6]{Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.   }%
\condition[1,2,7]{\the\tables.\the\floors.\the\columns}%
\condition[1,2,8]{Numbers replaced with text}%%This is not displayed, because the column is over the limit
\condition[2,1,1]{.}% 
\condition[2,1,2]{.}% 
\condition[2,1,3]{.}% 
\condition[2,1,4]{ Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  }% 
\condition[2,1,5]{ Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  }% 
\condition[2,1,6]{ Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  }% 
%
}%end conditionals
\def\cell{\vtop{\hsize=\csize\leavevmode\ignorespaces\conditionals}\hskip0pt}
%
\def\floor{\vskip0.5\baselineskip\advance\floors by 1 \hbox{\loop\cell \advance \columns  by 1\ifnum \columns<\limit\repeat}\cells=0 \vskip0.5\baselineskip} %floor is just another name for a line
%
\def\newtable#1#2{\limit=#2%calculation
\csize=\hsize \divide\csize by\limit \advance\csize by -0.04in \advance\tables by 1\vskip\baselineskip{\bf Table \the\tables\vskip\baselineskip }\floors=0 \loop \floor \ifnum\the\floors<#1\repeat\vskip\baselineskip}
%end of defnitions
 \TeX
\vskip2\baselineskip
Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  
\vskip\baselineskip
\newtable{5}{6}%lines and columns
Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  
\newtable{5}{6}%lines and columns
\vskip\baselineskip
Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  
\bye


@Mico Thanks for editing.

you probably just want \leavevmode\ignorespaces\conditionals in \cell but your numbering seems out by 1 and I couldn't see why you needed both \cell and \column count aren't they both counting the column?

@David Carlisle
As usual, you are right :-). Replacing \cells by \columns leads to the same result, and the numbering was at one point needless . But "\leavevmode\ignorespaces\conditionals" shifts the whole table to the right.

it shifts to the right as your counting is out by 1 as far as I can see (most of your code sets the counter to 0 in the first column)

@David Carlisle
Setting \columns=1 helps .. :-)

\vtop{\hsize=\csize\conditionals}

does not make a box of width \csize, it just makes a box in which linebreaking is set to a target width of that size, so if there is no paragraph text and no linebreaking, the box width is the natural width of its content, which would be 0pt for an empty box.
The easiest change is to use
\vtop{\hsize=\csize
  \leavevmode\ignorespaces\conditionals}

Where \leavevmode is a plain TeX macro that starts a paragraph, and \ignorespaces is then needed as white space at the start of the cell would not be ignored once the paragraph starts.
That should have been enough but forcing the cells to be the correct width shifts your content to the right on some rows as you were resetting the column counter to 0 rather than 1 so an entry for column "1" was appearing in the second column, with the empty column 0 showing having non zero width. In comments you have addressed that already.

Thank you, I have updated the code in the question.

In fact, this attempt is more a collection of so called minipages than a table in the classical way, but not really well designed.  A work in progress... :-)
